# Peculiar arrangement by a Geography teacher

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

A teacher from Africa was teaching Geography to her six students. She sensed that the students were getting restless and decided to take them to a circular playground for an outdoor activity.

---

At the playground, she stood at the centre facing a particular direction. Two students - a European and an Asian were made to stand together on the boundary location that intersected her direction.

She turned 90 degree in the clockwise direction and an Asian student from the remaining group of four students was made to stand on the boundary location that intersected her direction.

She turned further 90 degree in the clockwise direction and the remaining three students - two Africans and an Asian were made to stand together on the boundary location that intersected her direction.

---

"Start running towards me as soon as you hear the sound of my whistle. Whoever reaches me first, will get a prize" she said.

---

***Why were the students made to stand in such an arrangement?***

***What can be said about the nationality of the teacher based on this?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This teacher is positioning her students in such a way that they stand...

> ...at the position on a compass rose which appears in the name of their country of origin.

The students are therefore from:

> **North:**
>  North Macedonia (Europe)
>  North Korea (Asia)
>
>  **East:**
>  East Timor (Asia)
>
>  **South:**
>  South Africa (Africa)
>  South Sudan (Africa)
>  South Korea (Asia)

And given her position within the circle the African teacher is likely from...

> The **Central** African Republic!